# Kubernetes cluster become unresponsive after one node goes down

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

We did setup of k8s cluster on datacenter with 2 master and 5 worker node by using kubeadm for initialization  of cluster .Added  Cluster config for reference.

> kind: InitConfiguration
> apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
> localAPIEndpoint:
> advertiseAddress: VIP_ADDRESS
> ---
> kind: ClusterConfiguration
> apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
> kubernetesVersion: v1.22.0
> controlPlaneEndpoint: "MANAGEMENT_VIP_ADDRESS:6444"
> networking:
> podSubnet: 192.168.0.0/16
> ---
> kind: KubeletConfiguration
> apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
> address: 0.0.0.0
> cgroupDriver: ADVERTISED_CGROUP_DRIVER_NAME
> shutdownGracePeriod: 6m
> shutdownGracePeriodCriticalPods: 4m

**Version used for diffrent components.**
etcd:3.5.0-0
kube-apiserver:v1.22
kube-controller-manager:v1.22
kubelet-1.22.1

Issue we do have is once we shutdown node  one, then complete server start misbehaving and nodes become read only on most of cases.Even we are not able to run kubectl command.

Getting Exception in kube api log:-

W0128 11:23:25.351294       1 clientconn.go:1326] [core] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 127.0.0.1  0 }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0128 11:23:26.347009       1 clientconn.go:1326] [core] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 127.0.0.1  0 }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0128 11:23:26.352155       1 clientconn.go:1

Comment: which node did you shut down, master node or worker node? and the recommended master nodes number should be odd, not even, I think.

Comment: One of master node

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your etcd setup is not highly-available, it requires a minimum of 3 nodes to tolerate 1 node failure, otherwise etcd can corrupt data in a split-brain scenario

You should add at least one more node to etcd cluster (but 5 nodes is a recommended cluster size for production setups). Assuming that your master nodes are also running etcd, since you haven't specified otherwise, you should run 3 master nodes

See https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/faq/#what-is-failure-tolerance

> An etcd cluster operates so long as a member quorum can be established.

> It is recommended to have an odd number of members in a cluster. An odd-size cluster tolerates the same number of failures as an even-size cluster but with fewer nodes. The difference can be seen by comparing even and odd sized clusters:

| Cluster Size | Majority | Failure Tolerance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | 4 | 2 |
| 7 | 4 | 3 |
| 8 | 5 | 3 |

Comment: Thanks Andrew, i am aware of etcd cluster requirement the only challenge i do have is my product has resource constraint and thats the reason we need to run it in two node and yes etcd is also running on master.

Comment: Also just to update we are seeing same issue for 3 etcd node as well.